# Tamanho e posição do carousel Bootstrap na página

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

O seguinte código deixa o carousel ocupando toda a página. Como faço para posicioná-lo na metade esquerda da página e não ocupando toda a altura da página?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Documento sem título</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel style="width: 200px; height:200px; margin: 0 auto">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="Lighthouse.jpg" alt="Chania">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Chania</h3>
        <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="Desert.jpg" alt="Flower">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Flowers</h3>
        <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="Tulips.jpg" alt="Flower">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Flowers</h3>
        <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa o sistema de grid do bootstrap, usando as classes `row` e `col-xs-6`, faz assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Documento sem título</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <!-- We use the fluid option here to avoid overriding the fixed width of a normal container within the narrow content columns. -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-8" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-8">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel style="width: 200px; height:200px; margin: 0 auto">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="Lighthouse.jpg" alt="Chania">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Chania</h3>
        <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="Desert.jpg" alt="Flower">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Flowers</h3>
        <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="Tulips.jpg" alt="Flower">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Flowers</h3>
        <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
 </div> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Certo, exatamente isso que precisava. Só uma pergunta a mais: Com isso ficou fixo no topo da página, como faço para descer um pouco? deixar nesse tamanho no centro da página, do lado esquerdo. para que acima eu possa adicionar um menu.

Comment: pode usar o componente nav do bootstrap = http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-static-top, editei a resposta e coloquei um menu, p você ter uma ideia.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Não esqueçam de prestar atenção no fechamento das aspas duplas `"`
Faltou umas aspas duplas para fechar a chamada do `data-ride="carousel"` e após iniciar a estilização `style` ...

O código informado por vocês fica assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Documento sem título</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <!-- We use the fluid option here to avoid overriding the fixed width of a normal container within the narrow content columns. -->
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-8" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
</div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-8">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-6">


<!-------------------------------------------------------------AQUI-->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="width: 200px; height:200px; margin: 0 auto">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
<div class="item active">
  <img src="Lighthouse.jpg" alt="Chania">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Chania</h3>
    <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="Desert.jpg" alt="Flower">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Flowers</h3>
    <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <img src="Tulips.jpg" alt="Flower">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Flowers</h3>
    <p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
 </div> </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui pesquisando, é só colocar

```
style="width:100%; height:50%;"
```

por exemplo:

```
<div class="item">
<img src="Desert.jpg" alt="Flower" style="width:100%; height:50%;">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>Flowers</h3>
<p>Beatiful flowers in Kolymbari, Crete.</p>
</div>
</div>
```